# How to Get ID of the First Query and Use it to the 3rd Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem regarding SQL Query. I have 3 `Insert` queries in my code.
the first query is with auto-increment ID.

```
INSERT INTO master_tbl
```

The second Insert will get the ID from 1st query using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`function.

```
INSERT INTO process (id_ref, process_id, hot_cold, temp) 
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '4', '-', '12')
```

My problem is, I have third query which needed to use the ID generated in the 1st query as its `id_ref` also.

When I use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the ID it gets was the ID of the second query.

Any suggestions on how can I still get the ID in the 1st query to use on 3rd?

Comment: Hi Coder of Code, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: How about if you can take first inserted id in any variable and in third query you use that variable as value instead directly use of LAST_INSERT_ID() ?

Comment: you can declare the variable and store the first queries id in that variable and then use it wherever you want.

Comment: You can also use `select MAX(id) from table1`

Comment: Hi @Nagendra Nigade, my sql commands were in a single code?

Comment: As discussed , you have to take it into variable. So you can use above query also instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
whether you want this operation in php ? Are you confused to do it with php ?

Comment: Kinda! :D Please bear with me I'm a newbie... Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @NagendraNigade: `SELECT MAX(id)` is unsafe if other connections might be INSERTing into the same table.

Comment: @RickJames Yes..Agreed. In case of multiple client / Connection go for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the variable and store the first queries id in that variable and then use it wherever you want.

```
 After first query as you mentioned you are using the separate queries you can try using select to set the `Last insert id` into the variable and then use that variable as below,

   select @valuetoUse := LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Or Other way is use select the to get the value in your code and then pass that value to insert as all other values. For getting value you can directly fire `select`

```
     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

then in second query

```
   INSERT INTO process (id_ref, process_id, hot_cold, temp) 
   VALUES (valuetoUse , '4', '-', '12')
```

then again in the third query

```
   INSERT INTO thirdtable (id_ref, process_id, hot_cold, temp) 
   VALUES (valuetoUse , '4', '-', '12')
```

[For more info on how to use user  defined variables see here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: You mean like this:
`$sql=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO master_tbl");`
`$sql->execute();`

`$var=$conn->prepare("SET @valutouse=LAST_INSET_ID()");`
`$var->execute();

Comment: If you are using separate queries then fetch the value after the first query for the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` using `select LAST_INSERT_ID()` and then store it in your code and  pass to the queries where you want to use them.

Comment: `$insert=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO master_tbl ....");
$insert->execute();
            
$LID = $conn->prepare("SET @ValueToUSe SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
$LID->execute();`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ref_id' in 'field list''`

Comment: Make sure column name is correct. As error suggest `ref_id` is unknown.

Comment: HI @Coder of Code, I already got it.. :) thanks fot your help. I owe you a cup of coffee.. God Bless you

Answer (score 0):

Functionality is same as told by @Coder of Code But with PHP

Try This

Create Connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

First Insert into Table 1

```
INSERT INTO master_tbl
```

Then do

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as id from master_tbl";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$latest_id=$row[0];

$sql = "INSERT INTO process (id_ref, process_id, hot_cold, temp)
 VALUES ($latest_id,'4','-','12')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table3 (id_ref , columns list)
 VALUES ($latest_id,other fields)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: @khangkhungkhernitz check now as i used `fetch_array()`

Comment: Hi @Nagendra Nigade, I got it already thanks fot the ideas.. :) God bless you.